# Is there a module that helps link similar articles together and insert them into each other?

Tags: 7

I'm looking for the module that would allow me to manually link related articles together and to then set them to appear within the body of content - as links.

What would be your recommendation?

I tried to find different modules, but I need specifically something that could work by me simply creating links between different articles on a separate module settings page, so I don't have to enter into the EDIT mode for each article to add the connection.

Comment: I think you're looking for: https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/book

Comment: You can enhance the book module with https://www.drupal.org/project/book_helper

Answer (score 1):

You can set up nodes to be used like taxonomy items.  Take a look at this:  https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference

That module will allow you to set a content type as the source for cross-linking nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the above-mentioned Book module you can use [References](https://www.drupal.org/project/references) modul to create a node reference field together with [Noder Reference URL widget](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodereference_url) and [EVA](https://www.drupal.org/project/eva) modules. Here's a tutorial: http://mustardseedmedia.com/podcast/episode37